# What's the difference between vector and array in DolphinDB database?

Tags: arrays, vector, dolphindb

I find the following two methods when I use DolphinDB's C++ API:

```
Constant.isVector()
Constant.isArray()
```

When I try:

```
ConstantSP v = conn.run("1 2 3 4 5")
v.isVector()
v.isArray()
```

They are both true, so what's the difference between vector and array in DolphinDB? Are they the same type?

Answer (score 0):

isVector returns true if a constant object is array, pair, or matrix while isArray returns true only if the object is an array.